# SonarCOBOL Plugin Execution Error

Tags: sonarqube, cobol

I'm using SonarCobol plugin for analyzing the COBOL project and I'm getting the following exception.

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   com.sonarsource.cobol.XYZ.A.B.A: No license for cobol
>
> ERROR:
>
> ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I'm using:

- SonarCOBOL - 4.0.2.2656 installed
- SonarQube - Version 6.2 LGPL v3
- Sonarscanner - Version 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Error message:

> No license for cobol

clearly states that you don't have a valid license for this language. You need [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/) to run this analyzer.